# Device not compatible for app on play store

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, developer-console

I developed app in unity and upload its .aab file  to publish it on google play store.
Now my app is live on play store but it is showing device not compatible for app. I really don't know the solution. please help me.
Unity version- 2021.3.5f1
min sdk- 24
max 31.[This is player setting image for my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/im9yf.png)

Thanks

I tried to search the reason behind this problem but really found nothing.

Comment: What's the package name of your app? And what device are you trying to install it on?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check the minimum API level before building the .aab file. It should be as low as possible.

File>build settings> player settings> Android> Other settings> minimum API level

set it to as low as possible. Hope it helps.